# How to avoid nest 「null check」by "?.let"?

Tags: kotlin, null

let in kotlin help me avoid some if(null?) doSomething.

But I have a problem.

A is the field of the object, And B is the field of Object A. they can be nullbale.

They in code like this.

```
class Obj {
   var a : A?
}

class A {
   var b : B?
}
```

I knew I can do it by double let:

```
A?.let { 
   it.B.let {
      // a must nonnull
   }
}
```

```
A?.B?.let {
  // how to use A ,without null check again? 
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `if(A != null && B != null)`?

Comment: when A is a field , not a localVariable. It does't work.

Now, I edit the question again, the B is the nullable field of the A.

Answer (score 3):

There are extension functions out there to achieve what you're looking for, you can find them in this thread https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-null-check-for-multiple-nullable-vars/1946

But honestly, you're probably better of just using a basic if check here, if the variable is mutable you can assign it to a `val` first.

```
val _a = a
val _b = b
if (_a != null && _b != null) {

}
```

Edit: If you still really want to use let though, for this case you could create a pair and use `takeIf`

```
(a to b)
    .takeIf { (a, b) ->
        a != null && b != null
    }
    ?.let { (a, b) ->

    }
```

However the compiler won't smartcast the values as non-null, so you will still have to perform a non-null (!!) assertion on them.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement it like a *Swift* guard with an elvis operator `?:`

```
fun doSomething() {
    val a = A ?: return
    val b = B ?: return
    doSomethingWith(a, b)
}
```

Here `a` and `b` are non-nullable references to the data you hold in In this case you'd just return from your function.

Answer (score 2):

By default Kotlin avoids `null` values and for `Null Safety` it provides:

*1) Safe Call Operator( ?. )

2) Not-Null Assertion( !! )

3) Elvis Opeartor( ?: )

4) Safe Call with let ( ?.let{...} )*

- **Safe Call Operator( ?. )**:Checks if the property is not null before                       performing any operations.
- **Not-Null Assertion( !! )** : Explicitly tells the compiler that the property is not null and if it’s null, please throw a null pointer exception (NPE)
- **Elvis Opeartor( ?: )**: It's like ternary operator in java. If property is not null then left expression is returned otherwise right.
- **Safe Call with let ( ?.let{...} )**: It will execute the let block only if property is not null

> Example with Not Null Value inside property:

```
    fun main() {
      val name: String? = "Sumit"
      println("Safe Call operator: ${name?.length}")
      name?.let {
          println("Safe Call wih let operator: ${name.length}")
      }
      val length = name?.length ?: 0
      println("Elvis operator : $length")
      println("Not Null Assertion Operator : ${name!!.length}")
   }
```

**Output (With Not Null Value inside property)**
    Safe Call operator: 5
    Safe Call wih let operator: 5
    Elvis operator : 5
    Not Null Assertion Operator : 5

**Output (With Null Value inside property)(val name: String? = null)**

```
Safe Call operator: null
Elvis operator : 0
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
  at HelloKt.main(Hello.kt:14)
  at HelloKt.main(Hello.kt)
```

Here, safe call with let is not executed!! And Not-Null assertion operator throws null pointer exception.

**Your problem can use not-null assertion operator:**

> ```
> A?.B?.let {   
>     // If A and B are not null then only this block will be executed.  
>       A.someMethod()  
>       B.someMethod()
> }
> ```

Comment: This seems to me like the poster child use case for !!

Comment: Assuming B is not a property of A then this `A?.B?.let` doesn't even compile

Answer (score 1):

You can use when as an or statement for multiple variables

```
when(null) {
  a, b -> return  //for your case of nested properties try something like "obj.a, obj?.a?.b"
  else -> doSomethingWhenAAndBAreNotNull()
}
//or do something when a and b are not null here so you don't need to nest
```

Comment: wow, very clear and elegant! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to write something like this

```
fun <A, B> A?.and(that: B?, block: (A, B) -> Unit) {
    this?.let { a -> that?.let { b -> block(a, b) } }
}
```

and then use it like this

```
var first: Int?
var second: Int?

first.and(second) { f, s -> someFunction(f,s) }
```