# Kotlin .let {} null safety

Tags: android, kotlin

When using the .let { } function I noticed that when doing the following:

```
bucket?.assignedVariantName.let { 
    bucket?.determineVariant() <-- guarantee safety for bucket 
}
```

You have to guarantee safety for a bucket in this case i.e. bucket?. or bucket!! while null safety

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56764829/7254873

Comment: @AbhishekPharasi check my answer below

Answer (score 5):

Since `bucket` is nullable, you don't need to call `let` on `assignedVariantName`, do it like this

```
bucket?.let { 
    it.determineVariant()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin [`.let{}`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) method provides null safety

```
bucket?.assignedVariantName?.let { 
    // use `it` as non-null variable
    it.determineVariant()
}
```

You need to use `it` inside the let block to use it.

Comment: No it doesn't. But add a question mark and it works: use `?.let` instead.

Comment: @Cristan Silly mistake. I just added it. Thanks

Comment: `it` will not be `bucket` as in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Standard function **[let()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html)** provides **block** as lambda method expression to **callback** on invocation. So, variable on which it's being called is passed as it in argument of **block**.

So, if you use it on **safe call operator**, it provides you **non-null variable** as **`it`** in callback. You can also rename it whatever you want like below :

```
bucket?.assignedVariantName?.let { 
    it.determineVariant() //<-- You can directly use it here
}
```

or rename **it** like anything:

```
bucket?.assignedVariantName?.let { name ->
    name.determineVariant() //<-- Renaming `it` to `name`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because 'bucket' can be nullable variable there are different ways to make null safe calls in Kotlin, one of the standard method is using the 'let' function with safe call operator -'?'

So if you want to guarantee safety for a bucket in this case, it should be,

```
      bucket?.let { nullSafeBucket ->
        nullSafeBucket.assignedVariantName?.let { nullSafeAssignedVariantName ->
            nullSafeBucket.determineVariant() -- > bucket is null safe
            //assignedVariantName is as well null safe
        }
    }
```

}

Important to note -  bucket!! will throw NPE if the value is null which will lead to a crash, hence it is not recommended unless 100% sure that the value is not null.